# How to edit a custom function that relies on plyr to be dplyr compatible?

Tags: r, memory, dplyr

My script pulls down data from Wikipedia from multiple articles and checks if there are any anomalies in the time series for specific dates. Last week my function worked but now I get an error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size ...` despite no changes whatsoever.

I would like to change the following function so that it works through `dplyr` rather than `plyr` to see if that fixes things

```
test_anom <- plyr::ddply(output, "article", function(x) {
      res = AnomalyDetectionTs((data.frame(x[7:8])),
                               max_anoms = 0.1,
                               direction = 'pos',
                               plot = FALSE
      )
      # determine if the anomalies are between 2 dates
      anomalies <-
        ifelse(
          strptime((res$anoms$timestamp), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
          == strptime(as.Date("2017-10-29"), format = "%Y-%m-%d") |
            strptime((res$anoms$timestamp), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
          == strptime(as.Date("2017-10-30"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
          1,
          0
        )
      # find the sum total of the ones that are
      sum(anomalies)
    })
    test_anom
```

I'm not sure how to use `group_by` and pass the result into my above custom function but I think it should look something like:

```
output %>% group_by(article) %>% ...
```

Here's a minimal example that should reproduce the error:

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(pageviews)
library(AnomalyDetection)

#' function to pull down multiple wikipages 
get_wiki <-
  function(x) {
    article_pageviews(
      project = "en.wikipedia",
      article = x,
      start = as.Date('2017-01-01'),
      end = as.Date("2017-12-31"),
      user_type = "user",
      platform = c("mobile-web") 
    )
  }

#' which ones to extract
names <-
  c("Human",
    "Football",
    "Bird",
    "Dog")

# run the function
output <- names %>% get_wiki
output$date <- as.POSIXlt(output$date,
                          format = "%Y-%m-%d",
                          tz = "UTC"
)

#' check the anomalies 
test_anom <- plyr::ddply(output, "article", function(x) {
  res = AnomalyDetectionTs((data.frame(x[7:8])),
                           max_anoms = 0.1,
                           direction = 'pos',
                           plot = FALSE
  )
  # determine if the anomalies are between 2 dates
  anomalies <-
    ifelse(
      strptime((res$anoms$timestamp), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      == strptime(as.Date("2017-10-29"), format = "%Y-%m-%d") |
        strptime((res$anoms$timestamp), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      == strptime(as.Date("2017-10-30"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
      1,
      0
    )
  # find the sum total of the ones that are
  sum(anomalies)
})
test_anom
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `map`. You also need to change the column indices so they match the dates and page views columns. In my example that's switching from `7:8` to `6:7`

```
output %>%
  group_by(article) %>% nest() %>%
  mutate(count_anom = map(data, ~ test_anom (.)))
```

Comment: You could even use `map_dbl` instead of `map` to get a numeric column rather than a list-column. Assuming you're using `purrr`. Also, there's no need to define an anomymous function that just calls `test_anom`: use `test_anom` directly! Alternatively, you could use something like `output %>% split(output$article) %>% map_dfr(test_anom)`